# Connection python socket to portmap.io

Tags: python, sockets, connection

I have two python socket scripts (one for server, one for client). The connection is successfully, but once I want to connect to other computers out of my network, I get this error: 
`socket.gaierror: [Erno 11001] getaddrinfo failed.`
Here is a fragment of my client code, which is the one that gives me the error:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

host = "tcp://myaddress.portmap.io:theportnumber"

port = theportnumber

s.connect((host, port))
```

I'm using `portmap.io` in order to forward the connection to the server, so my idea is that the client connects to the portmap address, and portmap forwards the connection to the server.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The host part of the address tuple should not contain a protocol identifier or the port number (since the port is given as the second parameter of the address tuple). I.e.:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

host = "myaddress.portmap.io"

port = theportnumber

s.connect((host, port))
```